# Defining a new user password through Keycloak REST API

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to create a new user via the REST API, and I'm sending this POST

> *POST /admin/realms/myrealm/users*

*Headers:*
Authorization: Bearer (generated token, this part is OK)
Content-Type: application/json

*Body:*

```
{
    "username": "rahul",
    "enabled": true,
    "totp": false,
    "emailVerified": false,
    "firstName": "rahul",
    "lastName": "borse",
    "email": "rahulborse@yahoo.com",
    "credentials": [
        {
            "type": "password",
            "value": "rahul"
        }
    ]
}
```

The user is created normally, but the password doesn't work, when I try to
login it claims I have invalid credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add mapping `"temporary": false` to `credentials`:

```
{
    "username": "rahul",
    "enabled": true,
    "totp": false,
    "emailVerified": false,
    "firstName": "rahul",
    "lastName": "borse",
    "email": "rahulborse@yahoo.com",
    "credentials": [
        {
            "type": "password",
            "value": "rahul",
            "temporary": false
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please confirm whether this worked?