# How can I create a user with a password in Keycloak using the REST API?

Tags: rest, keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

I can create a new user using the REST API at

`http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/myRealm/users`

but the user doesn't have a password.  Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56526560/create-a-user-on-keycloack-including-password-from-curl-command) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58321304/defining-a-new-user-password-through-keycloak-rest-api) I added credentials to the json like this

```
{
  "firstName":"functest",
  "lastName":"functest",
  "email":"me@gmail.com",
  "enabled":true,
  "username":"functest",
  "credentials":[{"type":"password","value":"abc123","temporary":false}]
}
```

but when I try to login with the username and password it fails.  When I look at the users credentials in the UI it does show a line with Type `password` but the user label is blank.

How can I create a user with a password using the REST API?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Update:** The `/auth` path was removed starting with [Keycloak 17 Quarkus distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71902419/1366871). So you might need to remove the `/auth` from following endpoint calls.

Well you should be able to create the credentials using the endpoint:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/myRealm/users
```

with the payload

```
{"enabled":true,"username":"functest","email":"me@gmail.com","firstName":"functest","lastName":"functest","credentials":[{"type":"password","value":"abc123","temporary":false}]}
```

Alternative, you can create the user first and then set the password using the endpoint:

```
PUT http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/myRealm/users/<USER_ID>
```

with the payload:

```
{"credentials":[{"type":"password","value":"abc123","temporary":false}]}
```

the user `ID` you can get it from:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/myRealm/users/?username=<USERNAME>
```